# Search box for value within range but to stay in column

Tags: excel, vba, search, row

Since 5 hours I am struggling with the following code, which I'd love to extend. 
I simply want to mimic the built in ctrl + F search tool via an Input Box, adding the feature to stay in row/column (ActiveCell) while looking for the name (letters not numbers).

**working code:**

```
Sub Jarvis()

Dim sResult As String

  On Error Resume Next

  sResult = InputBox("Bitte Produktname angeben")

  If IsNumeric(sResult) Then 'row
    Cells(sResult, ActiveCell.Column).Select
  Else 'Select column - Here I want to add a way to search for names/values and to jump to them, while staying in the current column - Unfortunately didn't find the suiting command
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, sResult).Select

  End If

End Sub
```

**not working code:**

```
Sub Jarvis2()

Dim sResult As String

  On Error Resume Next

  sResult = InputBox("Bitte Produktname angeben")

  If IsNumeric(sResult) Then 'row
    Cells(sResult, ActiveCell.Column).Select
  Else 'Select column - Here I want to add a way to search for names/values and to jump to them, while staying in the current column - Unfortunately didn't find the suiting command
    Columns("AW2:JZ5", sResult).Select

  End If

End Sub
```

Could anyone of the pros help me out?

Comment: First of all you must remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides all error massages. If you cannot see your errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code cannot work! Remove that line and fix your errors. • Checkout the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help PEH.

Here is my solution:

```
 Sub Jarvis()

    Dim word, cellRange, firstAddress, c, FindNext, BottomRight As String

    word = InputBox("insert search term", "")

    If word = "" Then Exit Sub

    cellRange = "aw2:ku5"
    'change search range

    With ActiveSheet.Range(cellRange)
        Set c = .Find(word)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                Range(c.Address, ActiveCell).Select
                    With Selection
                        BottomRight = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Select
                    End With
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If anyone of the pros finds a more efficient way, please correct it.